# Vue Draggable clone and drag on event

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, vuedraggable

I am using [vue-draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) for a list of items that I have.

I want to allow the user to duplicate list items by right click -> duplicate.
When the duplicate is selected I want to clone the item and attach it to the mouse cursor, so that it is draggable and be dropped where the users wants.

I have implemented the context menu and the draggable already, I do not know though how to force the item to be cloned and dragged.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have updates for this? Can you share it?

Comment: @AbingPj no, unfortunately not